# c# get IP of a PC which turned network discovery off

Tags: c#, network-programming

I use the Ping class to test every possible address in the network. But PCs with the option: Turrn off network discovery do not respond to ping (windows can not discover them too). Is there any way to get the IP and name of these PCs?

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of turning off network discovery that you cannot discover them? I'm no expert by the way, but if I was responsible for maintaining that option, and there was a way around it, I'd be trying to close that gap.

Comment: Each user can choose this option freely. But APs and routers still know the connected devices and there MACs and IPs. I want my app. to do the same. The Turrn off network discovery option as i understand it prevents the PC itself from discovering other PCs in the network, but offcource it is still connected to the LAN, sending and recieving packets containing its info.

Comment: If you would be able to find them regardless of this option, they wouldn't really have a choice, right? And the option itself would be useless.

Comment: You can not hide an IP or MAC in LAN. Each packet contains these info and is sent through the network searching for its distination. You can even spy on data content sent to other PCs if it is not encrypted encuding (otherwise you have to crack the encryption). This is not the question. The question is how can I get the IP using C# if Ping class can't.